# regex everything in between html comments

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to remove everything in between html comments
`<!--` REMOVE `-->` in php using regex. can anyone lend a hand please

```
$str = preg_replace('/\<!--.*\-->/', '', $str);
```

Comment: You will need to look for `\n` also since comments can be multiline.

Comment: Don't use regexes on html. Every time you do, Alan Turing kills a kitten: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068

Comment: @prajeesh, and also use non-greedy matches, since there can be multiple comments in a single file. e.g. this is why regexes are a bad idea

Comment: i recommend using dom functions

Comment: It’s unclear whether you want to produce an empty string or `<!-- -->` after your replace operation.

Comment: @BenjiXVI an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `preg_replace('/<!--.*-->/sU', '', $str);`

Comment: -1, How this could match ``... <!--a--> some text <!--b--> ...``? Might be a better solution would be to use ``non-greedy`` parameter.

Comment: @Cylian, `some text` is not in an html comment. So it's not supposed to match. By the way, it's already using `non-greedy` matching

Comment: @Rob:Point to notice here that, OP here wants to remove the data between comments. So, isn't that case, ``some text`` will get removed?

Comment: The question is very confusingly worded, "in between comments" suggests just that – remove *everything between* (multiple) comments. Editing for clarity.